# error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator^'

Tags: arduino, altitude

I am attempting to write a piece of code to calculate altitude from pressure and temperature recorded on an arduino nano. This is my code:

```
    #include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>
    
    Adafruit_BMP280 bmp;
    Adafruit_Sensor *bmp_temp = bmp.getTemperatureSensor();
    Adafruit_Sensor *bmp_pressure = bmp.getPressureSensor();
      
    int temp = 0;
    int pressure = 0;
    int altitude = 0;
    void setup() {
     
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.println(F("BMP280 Sensor event test"));
    
  

  if (!bmp.begin()) {
      Serial.println(F("Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring!"));
      while (1) delay(10);
    }
    
    bmp.setSampling(Adafruit_BMP280::MODE_NORMAL,
    Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X2,
    Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X16,
    Adafruit_BMP280::FILTER_X16,
    Adafruit_BMP280::STANDBY_MS_500);
    
    bmp_temp->printSensorDetails();
    }
    
    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    sensors_event_t temp_event, pres_event;
    bmp_temp->getEvent(&temp_event);
    bmp_pressure->getEvent(&pres_event);
    
    temp = temp_event.temperature;
    pressure = pres_event.pressure;
    
     altitude = (((101.325/ (pressure/1000))^1/5.257)-1)*(temp +273.15))/0.0065;
    
      Serial.print(temp);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(pressure)
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(altitude);
    }
```

I keep on getting the error:

```
exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator^'
```

How do I go about fixing this? I am new to arduino and C and would appreciate any help
Thank you

Comment: When do you get the error? When compiling?

Answer (score 1):

`^` is a bitwise XOR [logic operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). It works only with integral types.

If you want to raise a number to some power, use [std::pow()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function.

Comment: @Mike if the answer has helped you, please upvote and accept. Thanks!